# Como validar um texto com expressão regular não permitindo tudo em espaço em branco?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Preciso validar uma linha de um arquivo texto, onde já tenho parte da expressão , mas me falta a parte onde da posição X até a posição Y tenho 30 caracteres que correspondem ao tipo string que pode conter qualquer coisa, que corresponderia à ER ".{30}", mas não posso permitir que seja os 30 caracteres todos vazios, como se fosse um campo texto obrigatório. Alguém tem ideia de como fazer?

Answer (score 1):

A regex

```
^\S+$
```

tem um match se a string e nao vazia e tem pelo menos um caracter que nao e whitespace. Logo, voce pode quebrar sua string inicial em duas partes, uma do inicio ate o caracter `X-1` e a outra o resto. Na primeira voce faz o match que interessa e na segunda a regex acima vai garantir que nao e vazia e que contem pelo menos um caracter nao whitespace.

Comment: Infelizmente, isso não me atende, preciso de uma expressão que trate sem eu ficar fazendo quebra de conteúdo. Imagine que terei uma string que comece com "01", depois tenha 5 caracteres, e depois termine com "03"... Os 5 caracteres do meio não pode ser "     ", poderia ser "01abc  03" ou "01    .03", mas não pode ser "01     03". Consigo exigir que seja diferente de alguma coisa, como no caso, diferente de "     "?